# FormContext.FormMode == DISPLAY after calling Edit Item in custom list

Tags: edit-form, spcontext, custom-web-parts

In a custom webpart we check on PageLoad the SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode to show different additional controls on edit and display mode.

If the list is created manually everything works fine. If the list is created based on a list template we consider a strange behaviour: the form mode in edit form seems to be always = "Display" even if a new EditForm is created. Also strange that the standard controls of the edit form are running in edit mode. Only the custom webpart receives the "wrong" mode.
Furthermore it seems to be that mainly forms which have been edited or created by SharePoint Designer show these effects.

Any hints where to look at?

Could it be that a created list based on a template got such effects or are we facing a fake?